# IIS7 Issues with ASP.NET Page migration from 2003 to 2008 server

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, events, iis-7

I'm having migration issues with a site that used to run on 2003 server 32bit to a windows 2008 r2 server 64 bit. and ASP version 1.1. Iv'e taken all the steps needed (I hope) to ensure it functions correctly. Such as,

- downloaded ASP.NET V1.1 onto the server
- selected the app pool to run this ASP version and set it to classic mode
- ensured that CGI is Allowed on the .NET version
- application is running in 32bit mode

But I'm getting the "This Page cannot be displayed" message when navigating to it with the browser. I noticed this error in the event logs -

`Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00db8960
Faulting process id: 0xcb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0b40cf800bfca
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 35c785b2-2000-11e5-be06-005056b20078`

Anyone have ideas on how to rectify this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: you say "application is running in 32bit mode" but application path is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe . This mean that IIS is running in x64 (SysWOW64) mode.

Comment: Iv'e set it in the advanced settings for its app pool. Enable 32-Bit Applications is set to True.

Comment: Have you looked at the Log (you can reach it from IIS - Website - Log)?

Comment: I have, Can't find any useful info there.

Comment: Here is a update, If I reset IIS and set the pool to 1.1, I get the "This page can't be displayed message". If I set it to 2.0, reset iis and the page loads, Then If I set it back to 1.1, it works! Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, find the ApplicationPool that is executing your web application

- Advanced settings
- **Set "Enable 32 bit application" to true**
- IISReset